# How can I use Joomlas <?php echo $this->template ?> in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, templates, url, joomla

how could I use `<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>` or `<?php echo $this->template ?>` inside of an Javascript script?
Like this:

```
!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('<script src="/xxx/<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" data-mce-type="text/javascript" data-mce-type="text/javascript" data-mce-type="text/javascript" data-mce-type="text/javascript">
```

or in a script tag which is not in the index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xxx/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/plugins.js"></script>
```

Comment: <?php is PHP and wouldn't make any sense to a javascript interpreter. It would simply not understand it.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript fundamentally cannot execute any PHP code. Remember that PHP runs on the server, generates an HTML document, and sends it back to the browser. Then JavaScript begins running. This means whatever data you want to use in JavaScript must already be on the page by the time Joomla is finished running.

If you do need to fetch additional content from Joomla, look into using AJAX requests. You could build a page that outputs `$this->template`, for example, and then request that page from JavaScript in the background.

Comment: Hi, I know the different between JS and PHP. Propably I want to say how can I determine the actual path to the template/website with javascript like <?php echo $this->baseurl ?>?

Comment: Again, you'll have to explicitly include that information on the page somewhere. JavaScript will not have any knowledge of where the `baseurl` is unless you include a hidden field with that value, store it as a `data-` parameter on an HTML tag, or pass it along in some other way.

Comment: I've had occasion to do similar things, so resort to echoing the joomla value that I'm interested in to a hidden input with an ID with which javascript can then access.